# Random.Range generates same number every repeat, how to change that

Tags: unity-game-engine, random, range, invoke

I want to do the most simple thing. Spawn enemies in 5 different lanes, constantly at random times. In this system, it picks a random number, and then at every repeat uses that same number.

```cs
    void Start()
    {
        InvokeRepeating("spawnRoad", 0, 0.5f);
        InvokeRepeating("laneOne", 0, Random.Range(1, 4));
        InvokeRepeating("laneTwo", 1, Random.Range(1, 4));
        InvokeRepeating("laneThree", 1, Random.Range(1, 4));
        InvokeRepeating("laneFour", 1, Random.Range(1, 4));
        InvokeRepeating("laneFive", 1, Random.Range(1, 4));
    }
```

I tried moving `Random.Range` into Update so it would maybe constantly generate a new number into the Float that the invokes used, but that just made them all invoke once at the same time and then nothing after that.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://answers.unity.com/questions/1072318/randomrange-always-generates-the-exact-same-number.html

Answer (score 1):

I was about to answer about generating a seed as Kaynn said, but I found that on Unity 2019.2 they apperently don't use Random.Seed anymore, but Random.state.

But the principle is the same, you feed a value to your random number generator. Depending on that number, different random values will be generator. So if required for testing you can generate the same numbers again.

One trick that everyone uses is that if you want different numbers you just get the current time and feed that number to the value generator. (see Kaynn comment)

Here is the wiki which have some examples: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random-state.html